# How does this conversion of base-10 decimal to binary work?

Tags: python, binary, radix

I've been given this program, which converts a decimal number in base-10, to a number in binary:

```
x = float(input('Enter a decimal number between 0 and 1: '))

p = 0
while ((2**p)*x)%1 != 0:
    print('Remainder = ' + str((2**p)*x - int((2**p)*x)))
    p += 1

num = int(x*(2**p))

result = ''
if num == 0:
    result = '0'
while num > 0:
    result = str(num%2) + result
    num = num//2

for i in range(p - len(result)):
    result = '0' + result

result = result[0:-p] + '.' + result[-p:]
print('The binary representation of the decimal ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(result))
```

I understand the first few paragraphs: we're just finding some suitably-large value `p` such that `2**p` multiplied by our number is an integer. Then we're converting this integer to binary and now we need to divide the result by `2**p`. I don't really understand the motivation in the last two paragraphs: I understand what's going on (I know what the program is doing), but I don't get why the program is doing this, and why this works.

Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: debug tip: print the result before, inside, and after the last loop

Comment: This is a common way to solve binary fraction conversions. Perhaps this video can explain it to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FA8yQ0cZyE Then, when you understand what's going on you can look at your code and see how your script does what's in this video

Comment: @The-IT The video doesn't explain why that actually works, though: it just explains the mechanical process of doing so. I'd like to know how that mechanical process is equivalent to what's going on in the last two paragraphs.

Comment: In that case you've come to the wrong place and (I think) asked the wrong question (Your question is about code interpretation...)
Perhaps go to http://math.stackexchange.com/ and lodge your question there... Or do some research on the web. It's pretty intuitive to me about why that works but that's just because I have a pretty good understanding of the binary number system. Maybe you just need to enhance your understanding.

Comment: @The-IT That's a terrible response to a question. It's equivalent to "I know the answer and you don't because you don't know as much as me". Not very helpful at all. There's clearly some miscommunication here. I'd like to know how the last two paragraphs in the program convert the base-10 number into binary, and your response was "here's a video of how to convert numbers into binary". It's as if you didn't even read the question properly.

Comment: @alexqwx Actually it's not a terrible response to the question. It's a terrible answer to the question, but then, I wasn't trying to answer it. 
I realise my comment above may have come out as pretentious, and for that I apologise.
I'm trying to tell you, you'll realise why this works when you realise how the binary number systems works. Realise that each bit is a part of your number in a base 2. The numbers after the point are for negative exponents, so the first one is  a half (2^-1) the second is a quarter (2^-2) ETC ETC. No need for someone to re-invent the wheal here on SO.